# realloc() works only a few times

Tags: c, arrays, string, dynamic, allocation

This is my code:

```
int main() {
    char* initials;

    initials = Initials();
    printf("%s", initials);

    free(initials);
}

char* Initials() {
    char* name;
    char* initials;

    name = GetInput();

    return name;
}

char* GetInput() {
    char* input = CreateString();
    char tmpStr[CHUNK];
    size_t inputLen = 0, tmpLen = 0, cap = DEFSIZE - 1;

    do{
        fgets(tmpStr, CHUNK, stdin);
        tmpLen = strlen(tmpStr);
        if( cap <= (inputLen + tmpLen) )
            DoubleString(input, &cap);
        inputLen += tmpLen;
        strcat(input, tmpStr);
    } while(tmpLen == CHUNK-1 && tmpStr[CHUNK-2] != '\n');

    return input;
}

char* CreateString() {
    return (char*)calloc( DEFSIZE, sizeof(char) );
}
void DoubleString(char* str, size_t* cap) {
    char* tmpStr;
    tmpStr = (char*) realloc( str, 2*(*cap) );
    if(tmpStr) {
        str = tmpStr;
        *cap = 2*(*cap) - 1;
    }
    else {
        printf("error!\n");
        free(tmpStr);
    }
}
```

This code compiles, however when I run it, it "works" only up to a certain string length - input of `kingdom` sort of works. However, `A horse, a horse! My kingdom for a horse!` won't because of `realloc(): invalid next size:...`. BOTH cause memory leaks according to `valgrind`.

The code is supposed to load it all using `fgets`. Then I will copy chunks from the buffer to array. If a potential copy would surpass array's actual size, I would double its size.

I tried debugging. For `A horse, a horse! My kingdom for a horse!` it works until `A horse, a horse` after which the loop enters `DoubleString()` second time. After this iteration, however, the array becomes empty! Which would lead me to believe the assignment in `DoubleString()` was incorrect but it worked until now.

So where am I wrong?

EDIT: Ok, so while my function could change pointed values, it couldn't change the pointer itself. `void DoubleString(char** str, size_t* cap)` did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: Where are `CHUNK` and `DEFSIZE` defined? Also, noticed the variable `initials` is unused in the `Initialis()` function...

Comment: Where I have includes and forward declarations of functions. CHUNK IS 5 and DEFSIZE is 10 if it matters.

Comment: `str = tmpStr` inside a function - what does this do?

Comment: `void DoubleString(char* str,...` --> `void DoubleString(char** str,...` or `return str`

Comment: Assigns string pointers `tmpStr` to `str`. My thinking is that if I assign `str = realloc()` directly I might reallocate unsuccesfully and lose the pointer.

Comment: I don't understand, `input` in `GetInput()` is already a pointer, why would I dereference the argument again?

Comment: The assignment within the function to the argument of the function does not change the argument at the time of the call.

Comment: @HichigayaHachiman what Oliver and others are trying to hint at is that your assignment to str: 'str = tmpStr', has no effect outside the function.  Your realloc may change the parameter inside the function, but can not change the argument passed in on the call to the function. :(  This: 'DoubleString(input, &cap);'  can not modify 'input'.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit Ok, so that's because while I can change the value of the pointer, I cannot change the pointer itself? Also I'm curious, when I assign `*str = tmpStr` should I free str first? Since I will lose pointer to the original `str` string.

Comment: To be clear, after `DoubleString(input, &cap);` is called, `input` **does not change**.  It has the same value after the function as it did before.   Think of `sqrt(x)`.  The value  `x` does not change due to the function call.